# How do I run the Topcoder Arena Applet under JDK 14?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-14

I just downloaded the [Topcoder Arena applet](http://topcodr.co/javaarena), but I am unable to launch it. I am on **JDK 14 on Windows 8.1x64.**

I tried the following:

1. `javaw ContestAppletProd.jnlp`

   Did nothing.
2. `java ContestAppletProd.jnlp`

   ```
   Error: Could not find or load main class ContestAppletProd.jnlp
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ContestAppletProd.jnlp
   ```

There is no `javaws.exe` in my JDK.

What do I do?

Comment: Webstart is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easy solution is to grab Java 8, as this still comes with webstart (`javaws.exe`).

---

I did take a look at the application, and it is incompatible with Java 10 or later.

In particular, it contains the equivalent of the following code:

```
if (System.getProperty("java.version").charAt(2) <= '5') {...}
```

Because the numbering has changed with Java 9 (`System.getProperty("java.version")` returns `9`, `10` ...) this will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
(If I think of it, it does check the first character, if it is greater than `'1'` - so it could work again with Java 20)

The jar is signed, and the signer is checked later, so there is no easy way around that.